# QGIS force saving edited data of layer

Tags: qgis, editing

I am facing an issue I found in QGIS 2.12.

My layers are WFS layers.

I use QGIS in a Windows tablet to edit some data in the street. After working for some hours in the street and editing a bunch of elements, I toogle the Edit Tool (Switch off) so data is saved in source(client) to postgis database in server (via WFS).

It usually has worked perfectly but this time it did not save the data in the source.  I don't know if the tablet in that momment had a internet coverage problem but the data was not saved in source.

In QGIS, on the other hand, I can see the changes as saved (Edition is switched off) and if I edit another element and save the changes, it is not saved either, and now I have internet connection for sure.

If I close the project and open it again, I am pretty sure I will load everything ok (without the changes of course) and everything will work again, but I don't want to lose the work of a whole day in the street. As said before, all that data is in QGIS project (I haven't close the project).

Is there a way to force all the data in the layer to try to save it to source, even if QGIS now is in a state where it thinks that there is no new changes??

Comment: I would not recommend going so long without saving mainly just because it's never good to loose your data.  Are you taking a live data connection out into the field.

Comment: @NathanW I am connected to Internet through a WIFi connection created by sharing 3G in my Nexus 5 mobile Phone. Although there are many times where I don't have 3G in mobile phone dut ot coverage problems in my town..Due to this my steps are: 1. Load the map with the WIFI in the office. 2. Go to the street, edit data during the day. 3. Return to office and save data there with WIFI.   I don't know why but this time it did not save the info...

Comment: I have used the tablet in the street like 30 times and i have faced this problem 3 times, losing all the data of the whole day..I really need a solution to this problem..

Comment: I would still suggest you don't use that workflow, it is not ideal and not the way its meant to work.  Look into the offline plugin, or some other method to download data local and work in offline mode

Comment: Thanks @NathanW, I didn't know about that plugin. Seems very suitable in my case..thanks again.

Comment: @NathanW  I have been testing the "Offline Editing Plugin" unsuccessfully: 
It does not work with WFS layers. When I try to convert the layer to offline QGIS crashes.
It does not work with MULTIGEOMETRIES
I get some warnings saying that it does not understand QDate fields (normal date fields in postgis).
Despite all these issues, I tried to use the plugin with a layer loaded directly from postgis and with a single geometries (No MULTIGEOMETRY). It turns the database offline Ok, I edit some features, but when I click on Sync data, the data is not updated in the database. Any othe approach?